# Declared property is a subclass, but my view controller thinks its its superclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

**Background info**

I have a view controller that is running a cocos2d scene (so I can put UIkit objects on top of the scene).

My app is crashing with the following error:

```
2014-10-25 11:20:04.426 AppName[24166:992733] -[CCScene avatar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c5a3270
2014-10-25 11:20:04.428 AppName[24166:992733] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCScene avatar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c5a3270'
```

I know that the reason the app is crashing is because its trying to call the getter method avatar on a CCScene, instead of the CHCreateAvatarScene which is a subclass of CCScene. If I look in the debugger, the VC thinks that my `currentScene` property is of type CCScene, not CHCreateAvatarScene so obviously it can't find the Avatar property. Am I declaring it wrong? I can't figure out why this is the case. I'm also a bit of a programming newbie, just FYI. Its probably an obvious mistake.

**CHCreateAvatarViewController.h**

```
#import "CHCreateAvatarViewController.h"
#import "CHCreateAvatar.h"
#import "CHAvatarAttribute.h"
#import "CHAvatarAttributeOption.h"
#import "CHAttributeData.h"
#import "CHCreateAvatarScene.h"
#import "CHAttachment.h"

@interface CHCreateAvatarViewController () <CocosViewControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

...

@property (strong, nonatomic) CHCreateAvatarScene *currentScene;

...

@end

@implementation CHCreateAvatarViewController

...

#pragma mark - CocosViewControllerDelegate

-(CCScene *)cocosViewControllerSceneToRun:(CocosViewController *)cocosViewController
{

//This will load the Spritebuilder file which is a loaded as a CCScene. 
// I then told it to expect a CHCreateAvatarScene because otherwise I was getting an 'invalid pointer' error. 
// I also tried changing the return type of this method to CHCreateAvatarScene to see if that would have any effect but it didn't, so I changed it back.

self.currentScene = (CHCreateAvatarScene *)[CCBReader loadAsScene:@"CreateAvatarScene"];

        [self setupSpritesWithAttachments:self.factory.attachments];

        return self.currentScene;
    }

...

-(void)setupSpritesWithAttachments:(NSMutableArray *)attachments
{
    int i = 0;

    //This is where its crashing
    for (CCSprite  __strong *sprite in self.currentScene.avatar.attachmentSprites) {
        CHAttachment *attachment = attachments[i];
        sprite.texture = attachment.texture;
        i++;
    }
}
...
```

**CHCreateAvatarScene**

```
// .h
#import "CCScene.h"
#import "CHAvatar.h"

@interface CHCreateAvatarScene : CCScene

@property (strong, nonatomic) CHAvatar *avatar;

@end

//.m
#import "CHCreateAvatarScene.h"


@implementation CHCreateAvatarScene {
    CCNode *avatarNode;
}

-(void)didLoadFromCCB
{
    self.avatar = (CHAvatar *)[CCBReader load:@"Avatar"];
    [avatarNode addChild:self.avatar];

}
```

**CHAvatar (I don't think its relevant, but included it just in case)**

```
//.h
#import "CCNode.h"

@interface CHAvatar : CCNode

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *attachmentSprites;

@end

//.m
#import "CHAvatar.h"

@implementation CHAvatar {
    CCSprite *_shoulders;
    CCSprite *_neck;
    CCSprite *_head;
}

//Have left off the head for now just to get this working.
-(void)didLoadFromCCB
{
    self.attachmentSprites = [@[_shoulders, _neck] mutableCopy];

}

@end
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: I haven't used these classes but there must be somewhere in your scene file (passed to loadAsScene) where you specify your class

Answer (score 0):

The declared type of a variable expresses an intention to the compiler. "I intend to store this type of thing in this storage." The compiler will set aside the proper amount of storage for that type of variable (in this case, a pointer) and it will try to warn about cases where the code is clearly trying to put the wrong type of thing into the variable. But it can only do static checks at compile time. It doesn't put in dynamic checks at run time. It doesn't check what the code is *actually* doing.

Importantly, the declared type of a pointer variable does not control the actual type of thing being pointed to by any pointer stored into it. Just because you have declared your intent, that doesn't mean your actions (i.e. your code) match that intent.

In your case, the expression `[CCBReader loadAsScene:@"CreateAvatarScene"]` is actually returning an instance of `CCScene`, not an instance of `CHCreateAvatarScene`. You have a type cast to tell the compiler to treat the return value as though it were a pointer to `CHCreateAvatarScene`. That silences the compiler from complaining, but doesn't actually change the nature of the object the pointer points to.

You wrote in a couple of places that "the view controller thinks" the object is of the wrong class and so can't find the property. This is exactly backward. The code is written to "think" that the object is always of the type `CHCreateAvatarScene` but it really isn't. The view controller doesn't have to "find" the property. It just acts as though the property exists by calling the getter method. It is the object that has received that message that doesn't know how to respond to it because it's not actually a `CHCreateAvatarScene`. It's a `CCScene` object.

The debugger and the error message are both correct about the actual type of the object.

The real question is how `+[CCBReader loadAsScene:]` works. Why would you expect it to return an instance of `CHCreateAvatarScene`? Why is it behaving differently than you expect and returning an instance of `CCScene`?

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me figure it out, so I'm posting the answer.

Basically, I was mixing up concepts of scenes and nodes in Cocos2d. Here was how I fixed it:

1. Change CHCreateAvatarViewController's property to type `CCScene *currentScene` and remove `(* CHCreateAvatarScene)` casting in the `cocosViewControllerSceneToRun:` method. In fact, I could probably remove this property all together after this solution is complete.
2. Rename CHCreateAvatarScene to CHCreateAvatarNode (I was getting mixed up with the concepts of scenes and nodes, so this helped). Change it to be a subclass of CCNode, not CCScene.
3. Add a `CCNode *avatarNode` property to the vc. In `CCBReaderDidLoad:` in the vc, add `self.avatarNode = [[CHCreateAvatarNode alloc] init];`
4. In the for loop where the app originally crashed change `self.currentScene.avatar.attachmentSprites` to `self.avatarNode.avatar.attachmentSprites`

And voila!